# How can I change the state of specific child component trough grandparent component?

Tags: reactjs

I have app that has **Layout** component which is main component and it has two **Bookshelf** components and each **Bookshelf** component has five **Book** components. How can I change for example on second **Bookshelf**, fifth **Book** state.taken to *true* or *false* from the **Layout** component?

It looks something like this:

*Layout.js*

```
    export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var bookshelves = [
      1,2
    ].map((bookshelf_id, i) => <Bookshelf key={i} bookshelf_id={bookshelf_id}/>);
    return (
      <div>
      {bookshelves}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*Bookshelf.js*

```
export default class Bookshelf extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var books = [
      1,2,3,4,5
    ].map((book_id, i) => <Book key={i} book_id={book_id}/>);
    return (
      <table>
      <h1>Shelf{this.props.bookshelf_id}</h1>
      {books}
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

*Book.js*

```
export default class Book extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var style= {
      backgroundColor: this.props.taken ? 'red' : 'green'
    };
    return (
      <td style={style}>Book{this.props.book_id}</td>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to update the example code to be able to change a book on only one shelf. In your example, each bookshelf always has the same 5 books, with the same id's.  So in this setup you cannot change a book on only one bookshelf.

Also, if you pass the `taken` parameter from the grandparent, it is a prop, not state.
You could use the prop and turn it into initial state, but this would only make sense there is some user interaction to manipulate the state afterwards.

Finally, it is not a good idea to use a mapping index as `key` in react. Better to use a unique ID.

Updated code would look something like this:

Layout.js

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // library is an array of bookshelf objects
    // each bookshelf object contains book objects
    // fifth book on second shelf is taken
    var library = [
      { id: "shelf1", books: [
        { id: "book11", taken: false },
        { id: "book12", taken: false },
        { id: "book13", taken: false },
        { id: "book14", taken: false },
        { id: "book15", taken: false }]
      },
      { id: "shelf2", books: [
        { id: "book21", taken: false },
        { id: "book22", taken: false },
        { id: "book23", taken: false },
        { id: "book24", taken: false },
        { id: "book25", taken: true }]
      }
    ];
    var bookshelves = library.map((bookshelf) => 
      <Bookshelf key={bookshelf.id} 
                 bookshelf_id={bookshelf.id} 
                 books={bookshelf.books}/>);
    return (
      <div>
        {bookshelves}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Bookshelf.js

```
export default class Bookshelf extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var books = this.props.books.map((book) => 
      <Book key={book.id} book_id={book.id} taken={book.taken}/>);
    return (
      <table>
      <h1>{this.props.bookshelf_id}</h1>
        {books}
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Book.js

```
export default class Book extends React.Component {
  // put initial taken parameter in state
  getInitialState() {
    return { taken: this.props.taken }
  },
  render() {
    var style= {
      backgroundColor: this.state.taken ? 'red' : 'green'
    };
    return (
      <td style={style}>Book{this.props.book_id}</td>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figuring out where props/states should exist is probably the most challenging and interesting part of using React.  As a guide for the philosophy, I would take a good hard look at the [Thinking In React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) guide.

But to answer your question simply;

Data should always exist as a state within the highest order component that needs to access it.  So, for this example, the actual data about your books should exist as a state element on the `Layouts` component.

Data is passed to children in the form of props, and is considered immutable by the lower levels.  I.e., your bookshelves and book components will not have the ability to directly modify the books data that they have.  Instead, they will utilize prop callbacks to `Layouts`, which will do the actions on the data in it's state, and as a result, will update the props of it's children, thus causing the appropriate re-render.

Data in React is one-direction, from parent to Child.  Children components should never need to ask anything of their parents.  The parents should provide everything the children need as props.